# Redis get keys from set, then get their data in multi

Tags: node.js, redis

I know I can write a lua script for this, but I'm wondering if it can be done using multi or pipelining.

I have a set that contains hash keys, I'd like to do `SMEMBERS` on the set, then use those results to perform `HGETALL` on each key and return the aggregate.  I'm using ioredis in node.

EDIT:

Including an example I came up using ioredis based on Itamar's comments:

```
  redis.smembers('users', function(err, res) {
    var pipeline = redis.pipeline();
    res.forEach(function(key) {
      pipeline.hgetall(key);
    });
    pipeline.exec(function(err, res) {
      var results = res.map(function(item) {
        return item[1];
      });
      console.log(results)
    });
  });
```

Comment: I think a lua script is the best option, you can't use pipelining or multi because the commands are dynamic, HGETALL depends on the results of SMEMBERS. If you don't use a lua script you need to do the SMEMBERS, get the results on the client then use pipelining for HGETALL, while with Lua you can do all in one roundtrip.

Comment: @Liviu - key names should be passed to a Lua script explicitly using the KEYS array. Generating them programmatically in the script isn't good practice as it isn't cluster-safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipelining is a good option here - after doing the SMEMBERS, pipeline all the HGETALLs.

Comment: Thanks, would this to be two separate operations? you wouldn't happen to have an example using ioredis, or otherwise would be really helpful.

Comment: I added an example, is that how you would recommend it doing it?

Comment: Definitely what I would do if I had any Node.js skills :)